# Nutch 1.13 is taking too long to crawl

Tags: java, nutch

I am using nutch 1.13 in local mode via java code which is called using org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner. It's running on Azure VM having 64GB RAM 32 core processor.
 I have four instances of this Java Application running on single VM.
To crawl 50 seed URLs with the depth of 4 and TopN of 1000 its taking 4 hours 
below are my nutch-site config

```
<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
  <value>16</value>
  <description>
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.per.queue</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>
   </description>
</property>
```

Can someone confirm if this set up is making full use of the multicore system or Do I have to use Hadoop explicitly?

Also while crawling there are a situation when I am able to get the desired child URL when the topN is 10 but the same child URL fails to get fetched when the topN is 1000, what could be the reason?

Comment: I would say that there is no easy way to answer this. You're crawling 50 different URLs? in 50 different domains? You should check how Nutch is partitioning/queuing the URLs (`byHost` is the default). Do you see low CPU usage on the server?

Comment: Luis, I missed out on one detail, as i mentioned earlier i am calling nutch from the java application . So, the java application gives one URL ( one url gets appended  to the seedURL list via ToolRunner ) to each nutch instance(out of the 4 instances ).

Comment: Regarding the URL which fails to fetch: 10 parallel fetches to the same host are allowed but with topN=10 I would expect that there are never 10 URLs of the same host in the fetch list. You should check the logs carefully for errors, could be easily that the crawled host fails to process 10 parallel requests or that the crawled server blocks your IP. You should ask its admin about the reason (I assume you're explicitly allowed to crawl this host with 10 parallel connections).

Comment: @ Nagel- the crawler dont stop when the TopN is 1000 , it just that a specific child URL(for a given seed url) that i am looking for is not crawled , but when TopN is 10 that specific child url is crawled .And there is no error(timeOut) on console

Comment: i jis the top command output at a given point ust crawled an url , it took approx 18 mins with depth of 4 and topN 1000 .end goal is to  to crawl 1000 seed urls in one go .